# How to convert html text to plain text in a tabular format in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one htmltext which contains text with html table and I want to convert this to plain text but table data should show in tabular format in proper alignment.

If first row first column is bigger length and 2nd row column is smaller then it should replace with space to make proper alignment

```
<html>test<br />test1<br /><table class="table table-bordered"><tbody><tr><td>Lin1-Test123</td><td>Line1-Col2</td><td>Line1-Col3</td></tr><tr><td>Line2</td><td>Line2</td><td>Line2-Col3</td></tr></tbody></table></html>
```

after convert the table data should show in a tabular format below

```
Test</br>test1</br>Lin1-Test123</br>Line1-Col2  </br>Line1-Col3
</br>Line2         </br>Line2       </br>Line2-Col3</br>
```

basically i need to replace additional space for less length value to make alignment proper

Comment: SQL Server isn't the right tool to do this.

Comment: You might want to use a CLR custom function.

Comment: any example plz? i want all in single string ,and </br> for like break , only one concern is how to replace number space correctly